# c# regex - match either a word or a number (int or float)

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

I'm currently programming a resolver for math expressions and have the following situation:
A user can either define a formula with parameters (a word) or numbers. Therefor I need to resolve a given string to either a word or a number that can be integer or float and I want to save the result e.g. as "left hand side" (lhs):
Unfortunately I have problems with the regex:

I tried something like:

```
Match m1 = Regex.Match("variable", @"^(?<lhs>((\w+)|(([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]*))?)))");
Match m2 = Regex.Match("1.2", @"^(?<lhs>((\w+)|(([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]*))?)))");
```

Expected result would be that I get a group "lhs" that contains the string "variable" for m1 or "1.2" for m2. Actual result is that I get the whole word "variable" in m1, but in case of the number in m2, just the first digit "1" is matched.
If I exlude the possibility for word "1.2" is found:

```
Match m3 = Regex.Match("1.2", @"^(?<lhs>(([0-9]+)(\.([0-9]*))?))");
```

Can anyone help me here?

Comment: Do you mean you want to match something like that at the start of string? And it can be continued with anything? Try `^(?<lhs>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?|\w+)`

Comment: Break down your problem into smaller problems: Build a regex that only matches word, but not a number. Then built another regex that only matches a number but not a word. If you have both regexes working, combine them as alternates in the complete regex like `"^(WordRegex|NumberRegex)$"`. Also, your liberal use of parantheses pairs (some of which seem superfluous) doesn't really help readability. Perhaps use one of those online regex resolvers (like regexstorm.net/tester, or regex101.com, for example) that allow you to tinker with regexes while showing the result against some input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\w+` pattern matches letters, *digits*, and some other chars, including `_`. Since it is the first part in the alternation group, once it matches a digit, it is never retried with the second alternative.

You may swap the branches, and use something like

```
^(?<lhs>(?<num>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)|(?<word>\w+))
```

Or, if the whole string should match:

```
^(?<lhs>(?<num>[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]*)?)|(?<word>\w+))$
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f%3clhs%3e%28%3f%3cnum%3e%5b0-9%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c.%5b0-9%5d*%29%3f%29%7c%28%3f%3cword%3e%5cw%2b%29%29%5cr%3f%24&i=variable%0d%0a1.2&o=m).

[image]